# Selecionar valores de uma <td> com clique

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

O código abaixo é de uma página, que o usuário digita o nome de uma cidade, e verifica se existem resultados parecidos. Com isso, ela trás vários resultados em uma tabela criada dinamicamente, dependendo dos dados trazidos dos resultados, isso já está funcionando Ok.

Preciso fazer com que ao clicar na linha da tabela correspondente ao resultado desejado, a tabela seja "limpa" e armazenados os dados da linha para que eu possa trabalhar com eles, exibindo outros dados relacionados a cidade selecionada na tabela, porém quando pego o elemento pela td ele sempre me trás o primeiro resultado independente de qual eu clique.
Alguma idéia que eu possa trabalhar para funcionar?

```
<?php include_once 'conexao.php' 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>INDEX Foruns Regionais</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script text="text/javascript">

    function mostraConteudo() {
      esconde();
      var nome = document.getElementById('td').innerHTML;
      alert(nome);
      }   

    function esconde() {
      $('.table td').hide();
      }

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").click(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    });

  </script>

</head>
    <body>

    <h1>Pesquisa cidade</h1>

      <form onclick="" name="formulario_busca" method="post"/>
        <input type="text" name="nome_cidade"/>
        <input type="submit" name="busca"/>
      </form>

        <?php

        $busca = $_POST['nome_cidade'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE cidade LIKE '%".$busca."%'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
        mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,$lista_Cidades);
        ?>

          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered"> 

              <?php
              if ((mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0) && ($busca != "") ):
                while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { 

              ?>
          <tr>
            <td id="td" onclick="mostraConteudo()"><?= $linha['cidade']?></td>
          </tr>

              <?php

                } echo "<br/>";
                  endif;    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)<=0):
                    echo "Cidade não encontrada";
                    endif;
              ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu __acho__ que você tem que passar o próprio elemento clicado na função. Exemplo:  `<td id="td" onclick="mostraConteudo(this)"><?= $linha['cidade']?></td>`

Comment: Porque você não usa os data-attrs do html5 em vez de pegar o valor do html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você está definindo o atributo `id` em um elemento que se repete na página. O atributo `id` **deve ser único** e **representar apenas um elemento**. Por exemplo, o HTML gerado pelo seu PHP seria algo como:

```
<tr>
  <td id="td" onclick="mostraConteudo()">Cidade A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="td" onclick="mostraConteudo()">Cidade B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="td" onclick="mostraConteudo()">Cidade C</td>
</tr>
```

Como `id` é único, o navegador só reconhecerá a primeira linha como `#td` e as outras serão ignoradas. Para contornar isso, você pode alterar para:

```
<tr>
  <td onclick="mostraConteudo(this)"><?= $linha['cidade']?></td>
</tr>
```

Ou seja, remover o atributo `id` e passar `this` como parâmetro de `mostraConteudo`. Assim, tal função pode ser algo como:

```
function mostraConteudo(elemento) {
    esconde();
    var nome = elemento.innerHTML;
    alert(nome);
}
```

E como provavelmente você terá que fazer uma busca no banco de dados com esse valor, talvez seja melhor você obter o `id` (do banco de dados) deste registro. Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
<tr>
  <td data-id="<?= $linha['cidade']?>" onclick="mostraConteudo(this)"><?= $linha['id']?></td>
</tr>
```

E no JavaScript:

```
function mostraConteudo(elemento) {
    esconde();
    var id = elemento.dataset.id;
    var nome = elemento.innerHTML;
    alert(id);
}
```

Assim, com o `id`, será mais fácil buscar os outros dados no banco de dados.

Comment: Excelente Anderson! Havia tentado de maneira parecida, passando this como parâmetro, mas não estava fazendo correto dentro do JS.
Grato pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Bom tem algumas coisas que precisa corrigir no seu código.
Sugiro posteriormente você visitar http://api.jquery.com/ para ter um melhor entendimento.

Vamos lá:

Utilize classe para elementos que vão se repetir o ID de um elemento deve ser único, no caso troquei de `id="td"` para `class="tdCidade"`.

Agora a parte que mais te interessa:
No código abaixo toda vez que você clicar em um elemento da classe `tdCidade` pego o conteúdo do elemento que foi clicado utilizando $(this).html();

```
$(".tdCidade").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).html());
    esconde();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
      $(this).fadeOut();
  });
  
  $(".tdCidade").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).html());
    esconde();
  });
});

function esconde() {
   $('.table td').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td class="tdCidade">Santo André</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdCidade">São Bernardo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdCidade">São Caetano</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```